# Feature Request: Request for a more up-to-date answer

Tags: feature-request

*Backstory:*

I came across a question today that I had been pondering for a while, and after reading and thinking about the answers I noticed it had been asked and answered 3-4 years ago. UX, especially on the web, is evolving at such a rate that having something even 2 years old could be completely out of date. I was considering asking the question again to spark a more modern discussion, but that would technically be a duplicate question.

---

**Feature:**

I feel like UX is time sensitive enough that a button to request for a more up-to-date answer is needed. This would take the old question and throw it back into the newly asked questions, perhaps putting the old answers into a separate section labeled by the initially asked question date. The person that re-asked the question would then take over as the author and pick a new answer as would normally happen.

I feel like this cleanly solves an issue that needs to be addressed soon as some major questions get outdated.

Comment: Why not just add a bounty to it and leave a custom reason "I think I would like to see a more up-to-date answer"?

Comment: That is an option, but with that the old answer would still be the selected answer despite picking the new answer for the bounty. It could get confusing for the bounty to have been rewarded for an answer that may contradict the selected answer. My suggestion allows less confusion as you wouldn't see old answers mixed with new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `deprecated` button. This term is concise, is widely known and in software it suggests it's not the preferred option anymore.

If a question is marked as `deprecated`, the new question wouldn't be considered as duplicated. It would be just a flag to indicate that it can be asked again safely.

Comment: This is a good option, then it would be up to the asker to then link back to the previous (deprecated) question if he thought it was relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This "feature" is already implemented in the bounty system where you can high-light your question (with outdated answers) and hopefully get more updated answers. Just hit the "Start a bounty" link on the question.

[image]

Comment: I've addressed this in a comment on the question, that this is possible, but can be misleading if an answer is given a bounty that contradicts a selected answer. Ideally the asker would go back and update but I think we all know that won't happen every time. Thanks for the answer though